How do you log actions on the backend?
I am trying to implement action logging on an employee management system I'm working on for my company, below is how I implemented it:
Modifying the global Request object:
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request extends LooseAuthProp {
      userAction: {
        action: string;
        targetEntity: string;
      };
    }
  }
}

This code snippet reoccurs throughout all the endpoints that I want to log actions on:
res.status(httpStatus.OK).json(form);

    req.userAction = {
      action: `action here`,
      targetEntity: "entity name",
    };

    return next();

And this is the middleware that handles the action logging:
const createUserAction = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
): Promise<void> => {
  if (!req.userAction) {
    return;
  }
  const uid = req.headers["x-user-id"] as string;
  const { action, targetEntity } = req.userAction;
  const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: {
      clerkId: uid,
    },
  });
  const requestPath = req.baseUrl + req.url; // e.g v1/route/resource;
  const httpMethod = req.method;
  try {
    await prisma.action.create({
      data: {
        action,
        requestPath,
        httpMethod,
        targetEntity,
        User: {
          connect: {
            id: user.id,
          },
        },
      },
    });
    logger.info("user action created successfully");
    return;
  } catch (error) {
    logger.info("error in user action");
    logger.error(error);
    next(error);
  }
};

What I want to inquire about is: is the way I am implementing this okay? is it good/bad practice? and if there is an easier way of implementing it what is it? Because I tried researching this but couldn't find any useful information about logging actions on your API, and the reason I'm asking here is because I'm the only developer at the company and I don't have any seniors to ask these things, so I would appreciate any help.

If you want to catch all errors in all route handlers in the same way you just need to add error handler as the last Express middleware with 4 arguments like this errorHandler(err, req, res, next) and in this handler you can add logger.error call and whatever you want else.
